# Post vote casts disappear after scrolling

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open any post and long tap on the score to view vote casts:

   > [image: votes]
2. Scroll page to hide score section from the screen completely:

   > [image: hide]
3. Scroll back and see that votes disappeared and only total score is displayed:

   > [image: score]

---

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)